# Dupire's calibration

Tags: calibration, local-volatility

I'm trying to implement a method for calibrating the local volatility model (Dupire's one). I'm working on the paper from Andreasen and Huge : *Volatility interpolation* ([SSRN](https://www.ssrn.com/abstract=1694972)). Is this considered to be a robust and commonly used algorithm for calibrating the local volatility or is there any other paper which might be better and  commonly used ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

There have been advances in that regard, but which papers are relevant really depends on what is it thay you may worry about.

For example, to compute a local volatility surface, you need to interpolate implied volatilities. Different approaches have been followed, the main ideas coming from the following two papers: [M. Fengler - *Arbitrage-Free Smoothing of the Implied Volatility Surface* (2005)](https://www.ssoar.info/ssoar/bitstream/document/22137/1/ssoar-2009-04-fengler-arbitrage-free_smoothing_of_the_implied.pdf) where the points in the implied volatility surface are adjusted to avoid arbitrage, and [N. Kahale - *An Arbitrage-free Interpolation of Volatilities* (2003)](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/228872089_An_Arbitrage-free_Interpolation_of_Volatilities). These are a bit older than the one you mentioned, but triggered the following: [C. Bender and M. Thiel - *Arbitrage-free Interpolation of Call Option Prices* (2019)](https://www.math.uni-sb.de/ag/bender/BT_interpolation.pdf)

Another interesting paper is [P. Austing *Finite Difference Schemes with Exact Recovery of Vanilla Option Prices* (2019)](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=3530561).

Moreover, Labordere and Conze have been working on the topic. [The paper](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=3853085) actually granted Labordere another [quant of the year award by Risk.net](https://www.risk.net/awards/7955845/quant-of-the-year-pierre-henry-labordere).

---